# Excel VBA Says Object doesnt support this Action?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `VBA` code that lists all files in a specific folder but it is failing with "**Object doesn't support this Action**" error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub ListAllFiles()
Dim fs As FileSearch, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
Set fs = Application.FileSearch
With fs
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .FileType = msoFileTypeAllFiles
    .LookIn = "C:Files"
    If .Execute > 0 Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            ws.Cells(i, 1) = .FoundFiles(i)
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No files found"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line??

Comment: File search does not work in since Excel 2007. you will need to use Dir() or some other method: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/applicationfilesearch-not-working/771afb4f-d948-4a37-ac8f-4366336a41fc?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx) :

```
Sub ListAllFiles()
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim foundFile As File
    For Each foundFile In FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path).Files
        Debug.Print foundFile.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

you will have to add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your VBA project